How to add an array with nested structures to XMP of a PDF/A in iText 7
I have to add some XMP data to a PDF/A-3 file.
This is the XMP data I want to add:
<pdfaExtension:schemas>
    <rdf:Bag>
       <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
          <pdfaSchema:schema>Factur-X PDFA Extension Schema</pdfaSchema:schema>
          <pdfaSchema:namespaceURI>urn:factur-x:pdfa:CrossIndustryDocument:invoice:1p0#</pdfaSchema:namespaceURI>
          <pdfaSchema:prefix>fx</pdfaSchema:prefix>
          <pdfaSchema:property>
             <rdf:Seq>
                <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                   <pdfaProperty:name>DocumentFileName</pdfaProperty:name>
                   <pdfaProperty:valueType>Text</pdfaProperty:valueType>
                   <pdfaProperty:category>external</pdfaProperty:category>
                   <pdfaProperty:description>name of the embedded XML invoice file</pdfaProperty:description>
                </rdf:li>
                <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                   <pdfaProperty:name>DocumentType</pdfaProperty:name>
                   <pdfaProperty:valueType>Text</pdfaProperty:valueType>
                   <pdfaProperty:category>external</pdfaProperty:category>
                   <pdfaProperty:description>INVOICE</pdfaProperty:description>
                </rdf:li>
                <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                   <pdfaProperty:name>Version</pdfaProperty:name>
                   <pdfaProperty:valueType>Text</pdfaProperty:valueType>
                   <pdfaProperty:category>external</pdfaProperty:category>
                   <pdfaProperty:description>The actual version of the ZUGFeRD XML schema</pdfaProperty:description>
                </rdf:li>
                <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                   <pdfaProperty:name>ConformanceLevel</pdfaProperty:name>
                   <pdfaProperty:valueType>Text</pdfaProperty:valueType>
                   <pdfaProperty:category>external</pdfaProperty:category>
                   <pdfaProperty:description>The selected ZUGFeRD profile completeness</pdfaProperty:description>
                </rdf:li>
             </rdf:Seq>
          </pdfaSchema:property>
       </rdf:li>
    </rdf:Bag>
</pdfaExtension:schemas>

It is an array that contains a structure that in turn contains another array of structures
I tried the following:

create the XMP Meta data

XMPMeta xmpMeta = XMPMetaFactory.create();


add an array

xmpMeta.appendArrayItem(XMPConst.NS_PDFA_EXTENSION, "schemas", new PropertyOptions(PropertyOptions.ARRAY), "schema", null);


add the metadata to my PDF document

pdfDocument.setXmpMetadata(xmpMeta);

By doing this i get the following result:
<pdfaExtension:schemas>
    <rdf:Bag>
        <rdf:li>schema</rdf:li>
    </rdf:Bag>
</pdfaExtension:schemas>

How can i add the scructure node to this array?
I tried to compose the array item path and add the structure to it:
String path = XMPPathFactory.composeArrayItemPath("schemas", 1);

xmpMeta.setStructField(XMPConst.NS_PDFA_EXTENSION, path, XMPConst.NS_PDFA_SCHEMA, "namespaceURI", "Factur-X PDFA Extension Schema", new PropertyOptions(PropertyOptions.STRUCT));

but i get the XMPException "Structs and arrays can't have values"
Unfortunately I could not find much information about iText and XMP.

Could you add an example for the output you expect, I'm going to have  a look but it would be nice to see a complete example result you expect.

The final XMA data should look like this.
<?xpacket begin="﻿" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 7.1-c000 79.cb7c5a1, 2022/04/14-05:22:35        ">
   <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
      <rdf:Description rdf:about="xmpmeta"
            xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
            xmlns:fx="urn:factur-x:pdfa:CrossIndustryDocument:invoice:1p0#"
            xmlns:pdf="http://ns.adobe.com/pdf/1.3/"
            xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/"
            xmlns:xmpRights="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/rights/"
            xmlns:pdfaid="http://www.aiim.org/pdfa/ns/id/"
            xmlns:pdfaExtension="http://www.aiim.org/pdfa/ns/extension/"
            xmlns:pdfaSchema="http://www.aiim.org/pdfa/ns/schema#"
            xmlns:pdfaProperty="http://www.aiim.org/pdfa/ns/property#">
         <dc:format>application/pdf</dc:format>
         <dc:creator>
            <rdf:Seq>
               <rdf:li>My Name</rdf:li>
            </rdf:Seq>
         </dc:creator>
         <dc:date>
            <rdf:Seq>
               <rdf:li>2024-04-24T10:46:15.682+02:00</rdf:li>
            </rdf:Seq>
         </dc:date>
         <dc:rights>
            <rdf:Alt>
               <rdf:li xml:lang="x-default">My Company</rdf:li>
            </rdf:Alt>
         </dc:rights>
         <dc:title>
            <rdf:Alt>
               <rdf:li xml:lang="x-default">RA 0123108157</rdf:li>
            </rdf:Alt>
         </dc:title>
         <fx:ConformanceLevel>EN 16931</fx:ConformanceLevel>
         <fx:DocumentFileName>factur-x.xml</fx:DocumentFileName>
         <fx:DocumentType>INVOICE</fx:DocumentType>
         <fx:Version>1.0</fx:Version>
         <pdf:Producer>My Company</pdf:Producer>
         <xmp:CreatorTool>HCL® Notes 14.0</xmp:CreatorTool>
         <xmp:CreateDate>2024-04-24T10:46:15+02:00</xmp:CreateDate>
         <xmp:ModifyDate>2024-04-24T10:46:15+02:00</xmp:ModifyDate>
         <xmpRights:Marked>True</xmpRights:Marked>
         <pdfaid:part>3</pdfaid:part>
         <pdfaid:conformance>B</pdfaid:conformance>
         <pdfaExtension:schemas>
            <rdf:Bag>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <pdfaSchema:namespaceURI>urn:factur-x:pdfa:CrossIndustryDocument:invoice:1p0#</pdfaSchema:namespaceURI>
                  <pdfaSchema:prefix>fx</pdfaSchema:prefix>
                  <pdfaSchema:schema>Factur-X PDF/A Extension Schem</pdfaSchema:schema>
                  <pdfaSchema:property>
                     <rdf:Seq>
                        <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                           <pdfaProperty:category>external</pdfaProperty:category>
                           <pdfaProperty:description>name of the embedded XML invoice file</pdfaProperty:description>
                           <pdfaProperty:name>DocumentFileName</pdfaProperty:name>
                           <pdfaProperty:valueType>Text</pdfaProperty:valueType>
                        </rdf:li>
                        <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                           <pdfaProperty:category>external</pdfaProperty:category>
                           <pdfaProperty:description>INVOICE</pdfaProperty:description>
                           <pdfaProperty:name>DocumentType</pdfaProperty:name>
                           <pdfaProperty:valueType>Text</pdfaProperty:valueType>
                        </rdf:li>
                        <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                           <pdfaProperty:category>external</pdfaProperty:category>
                           <pdfaProperty:description>The actual version of the Factur-X XML schema</pdfaProperty:description>
                           <pdfaProperty:name>Version</pdfaProperty:name>
                           <pdfaProperty:valueType>Text</pdfaProperty:valueType>
                        </rdf:li>
                        <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                           <pdfaProperty:category>external</pdfaProperty:category>
                           <pdfaProperty:description>The conformance level of the embedded Factur-X data</pdfaProperty:description>
                           <pdfaProperty:name>ConformanceLevel</pdfaProperty:name>
                           <pdfaProperty:valueType>Text</pdfaProperty:valueType>
                        </rdf:li>
                     </rdf:Seq>
                  </pdfaSchema:property>
               </rdf:li>
            </rdf:Bag>
         </pdfaExtension:schemas>
      </rdf:Description>
   </rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>                    
<?xpacket end="w"?>


Please edit this into your question. Answers genuinely are meant for solutions.

I think it would be better to create such xmp metadata separately as a file and then set it to the required pdf/a-3 file as follows:
For existing document:
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(outputPdf, new WriterProperties().setPdfVersion(PdfVersion.PDF_1_7));
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputPdf);
    PdfADocument doc = new PdfADocument(reader, writer);
    byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("metadata.xmp"));
    XMPMeta xmpMeta = XMPMetaFactory.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
    doc.setXmpMetadata(xmpMeta);
    doc.close();

Setting metadata for newly created document:
    String outPdf = "document.pdf";
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(outPdf, new WriterProperties().setPdfVersion(PdfVersion.PDF_1_7));
    PdfADocument doc = new PdfADocument(writer, PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_3B,
            new PdfOutputIntent("Custom", "", "http://www.color.org", "sRGB IEC61966-2.1",
                    new FileInputStream("colorProfile.icm")));
    byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(SOURCE_FOLDER + "metadata.xmp"));
    XMPMeta xmpMeta = XMPMetaFactory.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
    doc.setXmpMetadata(xmpMeta);
    doc.close();

You can do this with editing XMPMeta, but XMPMetaFactory.create() returns an empty object so you have to add everything manually by setting each property and namespace one by one.

That's exactly how I do it now :) I wanted to try writing the XMP directly but it seems to be more complicated than I thought.
